# Set checked/selected in checkedlistbox IF

Tags: c#, winforms, dataset, checkboxlist, checkedlistbox

I found thid topic, but I don't know how change my code to work with that.

topic: [Set checked items in checkedlistbox from list or dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13205105/set-checked-items-in-checkedlistbox-from-list-or-dataset)

My code:

```
        public void CheckSeat()
    {
        CinemaDataSetTableAdapters.QueriesTableAdapter tmp = new CinemaDataSetTableAdapters.QueriesTableAdapter();
        foreach (var seats in SeatcheckedListBox.Items)
        {
            string kom = "";
            if (comboBox3.SelectedValue != null)
                tmp.CheckSeat(seats.ToString(), Convert.ToInt32(comboBox3.SelectedValue.ToString()), ref kom);
                if (kom == "Exists")
            {

                //here i want select value as check

            }




        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't use foreach for this purpose because it will not allow to update/delete/insert at the time of iteration, use for loop instead.
2nd when you found the value within kom variable it means the checkbox needs to be checked for that value because that exists within you tmp. Now you just need to check the item, use the following code

```
        CinemaDataSetTableAdapters.QueriesTableAdapter tmp = new CinemaDataSetTableAdapters.QueriesTableAdapter();
        for (int i = 0; i < SeatcheckedListBox.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (comboBox3.SelectedValue != null)
                tmp.CheckSeat(SeatcheckedListBox.Items[i].ToString(), Convert.ToInt32(comboBox3.SelectedValue.ToString()), ref kom);
            if (kom == "Exists")
            {
                SeatcheckedListBox.SetItemChecked(i, true);
            }
        }
```

I've edited the answer, It will hopefully solve your issue.

Comment: HI, I get "checkedlistbox.objectcollection does not contain a definition for Rows"